# R - Faster solutions for base::interaction with character variables?

Tags: r, performance, dataframe, character, interaction

Consider the following mock data:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c("John", "Susan", "Eric", "John", "Susan"), 
                 b=c("K", NA, "J", "K", "S"), 
                 c=c("Smith", "Johnson", "May", "Smith", "Johnson"))
df$a <- as.character(df$a)
df$b <- as.character(df$b)
df$c <- as.character(df$c)
```

That looks like this:

```
> df
      a    b       c 
1  John    K   Smith 
2 Susan <NA> Johnson 
3  Eric    J     May 
4  John    K   Smith  
5 Susan    S Johnson
```

I generate a column called `unique` that holds a unique number on the interaction of the three character variables.

I use an `ifelse` statement to only interact column `a` and `c` if column `b` is `NA`.

```
df$unique <- NA
df$unique <- ifelse(is.na(df$b), 
             as.integer(interaction(df$a, df$c)),
             as.integer(interaction(df$a, df$b, df$c)))
```

This results in:

```
> df
      a    b       c unique
1  John    K   Smith     23
2 Susan <NA> Johnson      3
3  Eric    J     May     10
4  John    K   Smith     23
5 Susan    S Johnson      9
```

When I use this code to construct the `unique` variable in my real data containing several millions of rows, this computation runs for 21 hours.

Are there ways to speed up this performance? Any smarter solutions?

Is the `ifelse` statement the bottleneck here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would this work ?

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- as.data.table(df)
dt1[, unique := .GRP, by = names(dt1)]

       a  b       c unique
1:  John  K   Smith      1
2: Susan NA Johnson      2
3:  Eric  J     May      3
4:  John  K   Smith      1
5: Susan  S Johnson      4
```